# Reproduce the $count aspect of hist() using another function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, radix

So I have this function here

```
as.tibble(hist(dat[dat<228000],breaks=seq(0,228000,2000),plot=F)$counts) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarise(count = n())
```

This function will produce this.

```
  value count
   <int> <int>
 1     0    10
 2     1    25
 3     2    24
 4     3    24
 5     4    21
 6     5     5
 7     6     1
 8     7     2
 9     8     1
10    12     1
```

I can reproduce this using two functions

```
split_dna <- function(data, max, min, split, right = F, label = F){

filter(data, location <= max,
          location >= min) %>% 
    mutate(group := cut(location, breaks = seq(min, max, split), right = right, labels = label))
}
```

AND

```
count_dna <- function(data){
  
  group_by(data, group) %>% 
    summarise(palindrome_count = n()) %>% 
     ungroup() %>% 
     group_by(palindrome_count) %>% 
     summarise(intervals = n())
}
```

THEN

```
test_large <- split_dna(dat, 228000, 0, 2000)
test <- count_dna(test_large)
```

The only issue with the above is that I lose the zero values so instead of producing the above tibble it produces.

```
 palindrome_count intervals
             <int>     <int>
1                1        25
2                2        24
3                3        24
4                4        21
5                5         5
6                6         1
7                7         2
8                8         1
9               12         1
```

I feel like the issue is in the way that cut works? Is there a different function I could use that counts those zero places? I'm doing this more out of curiosity in understanding how different functions work, and to understand different ways of approaching the same problem so I can teach better.

You can use this snippet of the data to replicate an example of where a zero should occur

`dat <- data.frame(location = c(177,1321,1433,1477,3248, 3286,7263))`

Comment: What is the connection to ggplot2 here?

Comment: Apologies there is none let me edit the question

Comment: How do you use your two functions for the data you have shared? I don't see `group` column in `dat`. Can you provide expected output corresponding to the data shared?

Comment: `help("hist")`: "A numerical tolerance of 1e-7 times the median bin size (for more than four bins, otherwise the median is substituted) is applied when counting entries on the edges of bins. This is not included in the reported breaks nor in the calculation of density."

Comment: You use `split_dna("Your Dataset")` This should create a group column, you can then use `count_dna` It's inside of a local function and there is only one argument for the `count_dna()`  function (which is also "Your Dataset"), so i'm not sure what your question is @RonakShah I added another section to show how to use the two functions

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say by that @Roland... are you trying to say it isn't possible?

Comment: I'm not saying that at all. I'm just citing the documentation. If you want to reproduce `hist` results, you need to take this into account. Personally, I'd study the `hist` source code to see how this tolerance is implemented.

Comment: I have, it still doesn't answer my question though. I already account for bounds edges of bins in the cut function. The issue is whenever there is an interval, in the example data above the interval of 4000-6000 where there are no obs. `hist()$count` counts the interval and gives it a value of 0, while cut filters it out altogether.

Comment: "The definition of histogram differs by source (with country-specific biases). R's default with equi-spaced breaks (also the default) is to plot the counts in the cells defined by breaks. Thus the height of a rectangle is proportional to the number of points falling into the cell, as is the area provided the breaks are equally-spaced."

Comment: This explains that the function counts on the "equi-spaced breaks" and to "plot the counts in the cells defined by breaks" how do I replicate this using a different function?

Comment: I don't use `dplyr`, so I might overlook something. Where do you apply the tolerance?

Comment: The cut() inside of the mutate in split_dna() `mutate(group := cut(location, breaks = seq(min, max, split), right = right, labels = label))`

Comment: OK. Where do you apply a tolerance "of 1e-7 times the median bin size" there?

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding, when you reference tolerance I make the assumption it's tolerance of edges, I don't calculate the 1e-7 times the median bin size, because I'm not sure if I understand the purpose of it (in that aspect I should try to understand the documentation more). Do you think that specific aspect of tolerance has an effect on the question i'm asking?

Comment: Yes, I do think so. Otherwise I wouldn't have bothered writing a comment.